# Compare multiple strings to find best match

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

So what I want to be able to do is compare a string with a lot of other strings to see which of those strings has a better match

Currently I'm using re.search to get the matching strings, which I then use to split the string and take the half I want

```
company = re.search("Supplier Address:?|Supplier Identification:?|Supplier 
Name:?|Supplier:?|Company Information:?|Company's Name:?|Manufacturer's 
Name|Manufacturer:?|MANUFACTURER:?|Manufacturer Name:?", arg)
```

But this isn't really working out that well especially because I have a couple strings like this

```
"SECTION 1 - MANUFACTURER'S INFORMATION Manufacturer Name HAYWARD 
 LABORATORIES Emergency"
```

I want

```
HAYWARD LABORATORIES
```

out of this string, they way I'm doing it now, it matches with MANUFACTURER currently getting:

```
'S INFORMATION Manufacturer Name HAYWARD LABORATORIES
```

How do I fix this? And Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Some more strings I'm dealing with:

```
"Identification of the company Lutex Company Limited 20/F., "
```

Lutex Company Limited

```
"Product and Company Information Product Name: Lip Balm Base Product Code: A462-BALM Client Code: 900 Company: Ni Hau Industrial Co., Ltd. Company Address:"
```

Ni Hau Industrial Co., Ltd.

Comment: If you're trying for a *best* match, rather than *exact* match, I suggest the standard "cosine similarity" function.  You could also break the phrase into words and try matching individual words (exact, then cosine) to identify which portions will serve your needs.

Comment: @Prune Not certain that I've ever seen a "cosine similarity" function in python, and I've never used one before. If you have time can you whip up a short example as an answer to my question?

Comment: You're only matching the keywords, what do you mean by returns `'S INFORMATION Manufacturer Name HAYWARD LABORATORIES` ?

Comment: @sln When I run my program that is the current result I'm getting for one of the incorrect matches

Comment: @Worker: merely look up "cosine similarity".  No, I will not provide custom code; that's your task (along with the basic research).

Answer (score 0):

If all of your sections are the same in terms of the pattern `Name FACTORY NAME`, then you can try this:

```
import re
s = "SECTION 1 - MANUFACTURER'S INFORMATION Manufacturer Name HAYWARD LABORATORIES Emergency"
final_data = re.findall("(?<=Name\s)[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+", s)
```

Output:

```
['HAYWARD LABORATORIES']
```

Comment: They are not all the same, I could post a few more examples. The only similarities between the strings are the words I am currently using in the re.search. So far it works 75%ish of the time. Thanks for an answer though

Comment: @Worker as of now, you are using a number of company identifiers in an attempt to match the name. Is there anything else in the data that you could use to find the company name? Also, please post a larger sample of the strings you are using.

Comment: There is nothing else to identify the company besides the identifiers I have right now. The data I'm getting is unstructured and I'm using words that show up right before the data I need to extract as Identifiers

Answer (score 0):

you could use the fuzzywuzzy module to achieve some sort of fuzzy matching, basically you would calculate the distance between two strings, the smaller the distance the most closer thoses strings are.

for example, let's say you have a list of strings that you are searching for the closest match you would go as follow:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

string_to_be_matched = 'string_sth'
list_of_strings = ['string_1', 'string_2',.., 'string_n']

# we will store the index , plus the distance for each string in list_of_strings
result = [ (i, fuzz.ratio(string_to_be_matched, x)) for x, i in enumerate(list_of_strings) ]
```

for more information about the fuzzywuzzy module refer to [link](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/)